# JavaScript -is method not valid on the el jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a JavaScript method that worked before, but adding complex logic throws an error. `$('input, select').on('click', function () { ... }):` selects all input and select elements on the page using jQuery and attaches a click event handler function to each of them. When any of these elements are clicked, the function within the block will be executed.

`let el = $(this);`: This line creates a jQuery object el by wrapping this, which represents the clicked input or select element. It allows me to work with the clicked element using jQuery methods.

From some reason, in the console I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: el.is is not a function
> at HTMLInputElement.

```
$$('input, select').on('click', function () {
        let el = $$(this)
        console.log(el);
        for (var i = 0; i < paySelectors.length; i++) {
            var sl = paySelectors[i]
            if (el.is('[class*="' + sl.element + '"], [id*="' + sl.element + '"]')) {
                const action = sl.step

                if (action) {
                    if (sl.has_start) {
                        handleSelectorClick(this, action + '_start')
                        handleSelectorInput(this, action + '_complete')
                    } else {
                        handleSelectorClick(this, action)
                    }
                }

                break
            }
        }
    })
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: `at HTMLInputElement` means your `el` there is _not_ a jQuery element instance, but  the "naked" HTML input DOM reference instead. Why is your code using `$$`, what's the meaning of that?

Comment: This code is using a custom alias for jQuery selectors, and $$ is serving as that alias.@CBroe

Comment: Then I don't see how it should be throwing that error though. What did the `console.log(el)` actually result in?

Comment: Agreed with @CBroe

Comment: @CBroe it could happen if between the time that the "click" handler is established and the time that it actually runs the `$$` symbol has been changed to something else (something that isn't the jQuery function).

Comment: @Pointy yes, that would be about the only logical explanation I could imagine here so far as well.

Comment: Inside the event handler, just before `let el = $$(this)` add `console.log($$.fn.jquery)` and add the results to your question (or a comment).

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jquery')
    at HTMLInputElement  @freedomn-m

Comment: At that point, `$$` itself is an HTMLInputElement (a DOM node) - you probably have some other code that re-re-defines `$$.